# Promisifying a callback function produces asynchronous behaviour and unintended results

Tags: javascript, callback, es6-promise

I was trying to promisify the **callbackDemo** function in the following code:

```
function add(args){
  let val = args.reduce((sum, item) => sum+=item, 0);
    return val;
}

function callbackDemo(callback, ms, ...args) {
    setTimeout((params) => {
      alert(`Sum is ${callback(params)}`);
   }, ms, args);
}

function callbackDemoPromisified(ms, ...args){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      callbackDemo(resolve , ms, ...args)
  });
}

callbackDemoPromisified(1000, 3, 4, 5, 1).then(add);
```

But the alert provides **Sum is undefined**. However, if I put a log inside the **add** function I can see that it is getting called but the alert isn't waiting for the return.
Also on calling the unpromisified function like

```
callbackDemo(add, 1000, 1, 2, 3);
```

provides the expected behaviour. What am I missing? I'm not looking for a a solution that includes using another library to achieve promisification.

Comment: Your function cannot be converted to a Promise version in the way you intend. Your `callbackDemo`  runs a callback to get the data and then use it (in an `alert()`). Your Promise version is trying to use the data (`alert`) **before** you get it (`.then(add)`). It would make more sense for `add` to take a callback, that callback being the `alert`. Then, you could promisify it. But without seeing the big picture of what you're really trying to achieve, it's hard to tell whether that would be necessary or just overkill

Comment: Move the `alert` into the callback.

Comment: @blex Thanks for responding!
I am trying to promisify the mentioned callback based function without modifying the actual function! I wrote the promisifier based on the assumption that javascript passes on the reference of the function within **.then** to the resolve parameter of the promise. Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: @bergi I'm not intending to alter the function! Also this isn't part of a bigger problem that I'm trying to solve! The above situation is the problem!

Comment: But you have to alter it make it work. The problem with your callback is that it does two things at once: notify you about the completion of an asynchronous task, and run it to produce a result. Promises will only handle the first thing. Rewrite your original function to separate this into two callbacks.